# Using Path in object

Tags: rust

New to Rust, I am starting a small project to learn the language and its concept.

For this application, I want to create value object containing a field of type Path that I validate and initialize during the object construction.

My current implementation is:

```rust
use std::path::Path;

#[derive(Eq, Hash)]
pub struct FileInfo<'a> {
    path: &'a Path,
}

impl FileInfo<'_> {
    pub fn new(path: &Path) -> Result<Self, String> {
        if !path.exists() {
            return Err(String::from("path does not exist"));
        }
        if !path.is_file() {
            return Err(String::from("path is not a file"));
        }
        Ok(Self { path })
    }
}

impl PartialEq for FileInfo<'_> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.path == other.path
    }
}
```

When building the application, the following error appears.

```
  --> src/file_info.rs:44:19
   |
37 |     pub fn new(path: &Path) -> Result<Self, String> {
   |                      -         -------------------- return type is Result<FileInfo<'2>, String>
   |                      |
   |                      let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
44 |         Ok(Self { path })
   |                   ^^^^ this usage requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
```

Somebody could explain how to solve the issue?

Otherwise, what would be a implementation improvement?

Comment: The issue is like the error says: You are trying to store a reference to a Path object in your struct, but the struct has no guarantee that the Path object will exist for as long as it does. You could try storing the actual object rather than a reference in the struct.

Answer (score 4):

A good thing to do when you're facing an incomprehensible error with lifetimes is to desugar all lifetimes manually and give them names.

Let's do that (`Self` is `FileInfo<'a>`):

```rust
impl<'a> FileInfo<'a> {
    pub fn new<'b>(path: &'b Path) -> Result<FileInfo<'a>, String> {
        if !path.exists() {
            return Err(String::from("path does not exist"));
        }
        if !path.is_file() {
            return Err(String::from("path is not a file"));
        }
        Ok(FileInfo::<'a> { path })
    }
}
```

Now the problem should be clear: you're promising to return a reference with lifetime `'a`, but you actually return a reference with lifetime `'b`!

There are two ways to resolve this problem. The first (and my preferred) is to give `path` the `'a` lifetime:

```rust
impl<'a> FileInfo<'a> {
    pub fn new(path: &'a Path) -> Result<Self, String> {
        if !path.exists() {
            return Err(String::from("path does not exist"));
        }
        if !path.is_file() {
            return Err(String::from("path is not a file"));
        }
        Ok(Self { path })
    }
}
```

The second is to give the return type the `'b` lifetime:

```rust
impl<'a> FileInfo<'a> {
    pub fn new<'b>(path: &'b Path) -> Result<FileInfo<'b>, String> {
        if !path.exists() {
            return Err(String::from("path does not exist"));
        }
        if !path.is_file() {
            return Err(String::from("path is not a file"));
        }
        Ok(FileInfo { path })
    }
}
```

Or in short:

```rust
impl FileInfo<'_> {
    pub fn new(path: &Path) -> Result<FileInfo<'_>, String> {
        if !path.exists() {
            return Err(String::from("path does not exist"));
        }
        if !path.is_file() {
            return Err(String::from("path is not a file"));
        }
        Ok(FileInfo { path })
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a third way to fix the issue, and that's to move the `Path` into the struct instead of taking a reference.

Comment: @Jmb It's hard with `Path` since it's a DST, but you can take a `PathBuf`.